# Is there a "pipe" operator in Raku?

Tags: raku

I mean the reverse application operator. For example in Haskell it would be `&`:

```hs
ghci> import Data.Function ((&))
ghci> 2 & (+ 1)
3
```

In Raku I saw `==>` feed operator, but that doesn't seem to work with lambdas?

```
> (* + 1)(2)
3
> 2 ==> (* + 1)
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling:
Only routine calls or variables that can '.push' may appear on either side of feed operators.
------> 2 ==> ⏏(* + 1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With feed operator `==>`

```raku
2 ==> (* + 1)()
```

or

```raku
2 ==> &[+](1)
```

With `andthen`

```raku
2 andthen * + 1
```

or

```raku
2 andthen $_ + 1
```

Comment: Damn, what a stupid mistake on my part :'D. I guess I am too used to JS/TS and Haskell... Thank you.

Comment: We're all here to learn, @menfon!

Answer (score 6):

In the Raku REPL:

```
> 2 ==> sum()
2
> 2 ==> sum(0)
2
> 2 ==> sum(1)
3
```

Also:

```
> my $a = 2
2
> $a ==> sum()
2
> $a ==> sum(0)
2
> $a ==> sum(1)
3
```

Also:

```
> my $b = 2
2
> sum() <== $b
2
> sum(0) <== $b
2
> sum(1) <== $b
3
```